# How to use ST_Distance (Closest polygon to point)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon

Can I know how to interpret this SELECT statement for PostGIS? I am unsure where do I insert my own coordinates in this statement.

```
SELECT geom 
FROM polys, points 
WHERE points.gid=1 AND ST_DWithin(poly.geom, points.geom, 1000) 
ORDER BY ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Instead of a point layer (points) would you like to define a point by coordinates? Your query is not correct, "SELECT polys.geom" or SELECT points.geom" necessary to distinguish between the two geom columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query seaches for the polygon closest to a point that is stored in another table.

If you have only the coordinates, leave out that table, and construct the point geometry manually:

```sql
SELECT geom
FROM polys
ORDER BY geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1111, 2222), 4326)
LIMIT 1;
```

where `1111` and `2222` are the coordinates, and `4326` is the SRID of the polygon table (if you do not know it, call [Find_SRID](https://postgis.net/docs/Find_SRID.html)).